# Can't install any software on 16.04 while using live flash drive, is this normal? [First time linux user]

Tags: 16.04, pidgin

I've been waiting 16.04 release to install my first linux ever. I just tried using new 16.04 from live flash drive, without installing, and it seems like I can't install any software. "Ubuntu software" has no packages it seems apart of those which already installed, I tried searching for Pidging, but couldn't find anything. Also I tried installing pidgin with command terminal (adding distro, updating it, and installing pidgin) but it gives me error unable to locate package or something, same thing with f.lux software when I tried to install it with command terminal. Thanks.

Comment: How big is the USB drive? Did you make the USB persistent when you made it? If not, you won't be able to install anything or make any changes. Test it like a DVD. Even if you install something it will be lost when you reboot.

Comment: USB drive is 8 Gb, I didn't make it persistent or anything (don't  really know what that is). I just booted from it and choose and option of trying ubuntu without installing it. is this why I can't install anything? it will all work when I permanently install it on hard drive? Thanks for helping out.

Comment: I don't know why you couldn't install anything. Were you able to get on the internet while trying Ubuntu? Sounds like a connection problem. But even if you could it would only last until a reboot or power off. Once you install on hard drive you will be able to make changes install uninstall as you wish.

Comment: It may be something temporary. Others were having similar problems. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/760278/the-new-software-center-in-ubuntu-16-04-shows-no-application-data-found

Comment: yes. everything works perfectly, I have internet. it's just that "ubuntu software" app has in it only packages which are already installed and nothing more, i literally can't find there anything to install.

Comment: Can you please open a terminal (Alt+F2), run `sudo apt-get update` and try the Software Center again?

Answer (score 0):

To be quick, Yes this is completely normal, ubuntu software in live sessions should have very little software, if any, but when you boot up normally, from an installed version, all of it will be there.