# Software Center gives me a blank list of programs on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-center

When I open the Software Center on 16.04 it only shows me the categories of the programs available. If I click on one, it just gives me a blank list of programs. I cannot remove or install programs now.

I've tried `sudo apt-get update` and upgrade but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the error message you get when you try `sudo apt-get update` Without further information I can only assume what's wrong. (Best guess is attempt to run command with software center still open (lock file))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The new software center in Ubuntu 16.04 shows no application data found](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760278/the-new-software-center-in-ubuntu-16-04-shows-no-application-data-found)

Answer (score 2):

Possible just restarting the application will cause it to reload properly:

```
$ killall gnome-software
```

Then launch the Ubuntu Software application.

If that doesn't resolve the issue, ensure that the issue isn't with the apt cache:

```
$ sudo apt clean
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

Then launch the Ubuntu Software application.

If the above doesn't resolve it, then the steps will vary based on which version of Ubuntu.

With Ubuntu 16.04:

Remove the storage used by gnome-software:

```
$ killall gnome-software
$ rm -rf ~/.local/share/gnome-software
```

Then launch the Ubuntu Software application.

If that still doesn't resolve it, try to reinstall gnome-software

```
$ killall gnome-software
$ sudo apt gnome-software
$ sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Then launch the Ubuntu Software application.

The above suggestions are adapted from the article [Ubuntu Software Center Not Working? Here Are the Fixes](https://www.maketecheasier.com/ubuntu-software-center-not-working-fixes).

With Ubuntu 18.04 and higher:

Remove the storage used by the snap-store:

```
$ killall snap-store
$ rm -rf ~/snap/snap-store
```

Then launch the Ubuntu Software application.

It might not hurt to log off and log back in (or reboot even).

Answer (score 2):

I just realized that I just need to wait for the software center to load the list of apps. Center makes it without any visual indication, so you just see an empty list when you open some app category, and it will be uploaded in about 20-30 seconds. So if someone has this problem, they just need to try to wait first. It's ridiculous how unfriendly apps can be for the most popular desktop distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing it by removing the cache:

- reboot
- goto terminal (ctrl+alt+t)
- command: `mv ~/.cache/software-center{,.bak}`

Good luck!

Comment: I know this is an old question but I have same problem I tried your solution but got error - mv: cannot stat '/home/kerry/.cache/software-center': No such file or directory

Comment: Probably because the cache files are not there. You can easily check manually using nautilus. (check "Show hidden files" in Nautilus to make the /.cache folder visible). You could also open "Software & Updates" and choose another server for "Download From". Otherwise you could post a new question here on askubuntu.com.

Comment: ps. I see that software-center on my machine is using gnome-software. Maybe you could try to clean its cache instead. 
`mv ~/.cache/gnome-software{,.bak}`