# How to fix Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center

Ubuntu Software Center doesn't work:

[image: Screenshot of Ubuntu Software Center]

Comment: Try opening a terminal (press Ctrl+Alt+T) and running `sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade -y`. Then, once that finishes, Ubuntu Software Center might work.

Comment: You could also check what is going wrong by typing  `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` in terminal. Then try to open Ubuntu Software Center again and review the log.

Comment: I had this proble with ubuntu 16.04, and [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/761488/178497) fixed it all for me.

Comment: @ Chai T.Rix , Thrasher i tried your  codes but it still dose not work   @ phil Hirschhorn  i tried  the three codes in the answer but  
ubuntu soft ware center was disapper

Comment: @heshamkhamis Make sure you have run `install` command.

Comment: @ Liso  I also run `sudo apt-get install software-center` but this command gave me old version

Answer (score 1):

My Software Center was quitting on its own without even showing anything except the primary screen without any icons for any software. Thanks to Chai T.Rex, now it's working like a new machine.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Ubuntu Software should solve the problem, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt purge gnome-software ubuntu-software
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install gnome-software ubuntu-software
```

<sub>[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/761488/253251)</sub>

If above method is not working (which you already [mention](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865255/how-to-fix-ubuntu-software-center#comment1337376_865255) it), try removing Gnome Software cache:

```
 rm -R ~/.cache/gnome-software
```

Comment: `rm: cannot remove '/home/hk/.cache/gnome-software': No such file or directory`